# Transition to C++0x from C++98

Tags: c++, resources, c++11, transition

As someone who hasn't followed the C++0x - now C++1x - story and developments closely, I am considering that it is nearing the time when I need to come up to speed with the 'released' version. I also am not really interested in looking over the standard immediately. Therefore:

- What resources are there that give the "effective changelog" between language versions?
- What books/articles are there that probe into the use of the new features?

(marked as community wiki, if there are other good questions that relate to the transition, put them up)

Comment: On the bright side, C++0x only adds about 500 pages to the C++03 standard ;-)  The final committee draft of the language standard can be found at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf **[huge PDF link]**

Comment: @James: I'll get *right* on that.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the closest of which I'm aware is Bjarne's [C++0x FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's not very detailed, but the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x) has a decent overview of the new features.  What I'd recommend is use that to decide which new features are most interesting to you and then study those in more depth.

Answer (score 1):

C++0x is not "released" yet, the final ISO standard has not been published. At the moment they are at a "Final Committee Draft" (FCD) phase which basically means all the the features are set in stone now the committee are making corrections and/or clarifications to the draft before it is finally published with an estimated date of early next year (March 2011).

As of current there are no publicly released C++ compilers that have implemented all of the features of C++0x (like constexpr). GCC has the most and the newest version of the VC++ compiler (11 in vs2010) only supports something like a quarter of it.

Comment: Scott Meyers has a [page where he lists which compilers implement which features of the upcoming standard](http://www.aristeia.com/C++0x/C++0xFeatureAvailability.htm).